# What is the path from BITMAP[+WAVE(s)] to RTSP (Twitch) via C/C++ in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, libav

So I'm trying to get a basic tool to output video/audio(s) to Twitch. I'm new to this side (AV) of programming so I'm not even sure what to look for. I'm trying to use mainly Windows infrastructure and third party where not available.

What are the steps of getting raw bitmap and wave data into a codec and then into a rtsp client and finally showing up on Twitch? I'm not looking for code. I'm looking for concepts so I can search for as I'm not absolutely sure what to search for. I'd rather not go through OBS source code to figure it out and use that as last resort.

So I capture the monitor via Output Duplication and also the Sound on the system as a wave and the microphone as another wave. I'm trying to push this to Twitch. I know that there's Media Foundation on Windows but I don't know how far to streaming it can get as I assume there no netcode integrated in it? And also the libav* collection in FFMPEG.

What are the basic steps of sending bitmap/wave to Twitch via any of thee above libraries or even others as long as they work on Windows. Please don't add code, I just need a not very long conceptual explanation and I'll take it from there. Try to cover also how bitrate and framerate gets regulated (do I have do it or the codec does it)?

Assume absolute noob level in this area (concept-wise not code-wise).

Comment: OBS is Open Source and looking at it should answer all your questions https://obsproject.com/

Comment: @RichardCritten I know. I'm still waiting to see if I get hit by one of the big-brains on SO that explains hard things really easy and short and then I can just implement it without deep code diving. :)

Comment: Please ask one question per post. You need color range conversions, audio compression, video compression, packaging and data transmissions.